# creating a new MVC files fails to work

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have a cakephp application made by previous employees, 
its structure is defined as what can be seen from the following image
I am now stuck at how to figure out what I should do in my current situation in which I am asked to add in another controller, model and view accordingly. 
In the views folder there are folders to store different views that match particular controllers and models. I also created one folder and named it as new_foo.

Now you see the app_controller.php ? the file that contains all information available to initialize the menus (navigation bar) that are to call any controllers.

The menu is defined as an array, e.g

```
menu=array(
    array(
        'label' => __("Menu Item", true),
        'controller' => 'MenuController',
        'action' => 'MenuAction'
                        ),
    array(
        'label' => __("Another item", true),
        'controller' => 'AnotherMenusController',
        'action' => 'AnotherAction'
        ));
```

I also defined one such an element then created myself a new controller class such as

AnotherMenusController.php // please note the plural

```
class  AnotherMenusController extends AppController
{
    $this->loadModel('AnotherMenu'); // Please note the plural
    function AnotherAction()
    {
        $this->AnotherMenu->modelFunc();    
    }
}
```

And i also created a model class similar to this

```
class AnotherMenu extends AppModel
{
    function modelFunc()
    {
        print_r("Oh that is it ?");
    }   
}
```

However, when I try to run the application in my localhost, I always am reported with an error as

> Not Found   Error: The requested address '/anothermenus/anotheraction'
>   was not found on this server.

although i could already create a link in the menu item, oh well that seems irrelevant. I am desperate wishing if only there might be someone being able to shed a light on this for me to feel a little better. I am thankful for any help you offered.

Again thank you so much for your concern.

the image is in the following link

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjQok.jpg

My current problem is that the server doesn't recognize my controller function, what should I change now ?

I should have missed registering something for it to work out for me in this particular issue.

Comment: have you created the view file? have you tried to access that page directly without using the menu and checking the names to be case sensitive to ensure it is working correctly?

Comment: The view file is ctp I have no idea what are you suggesting, could you be more specific ?

Comment: Could someone help me please ?

Comment: Which CakePHP version do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess would be that your problem is that your local webserver is not respecting the .htaccess. The route the menu is redirecting you to is '/anothermenus/anotheraction' but the webserver reports that such path doesn't exist. It is possible that the app is configured for production use and your local webserver isn't configured exactly the same.

Check what happens with other menus and if the paths they link to are similar to the one of the menu you added or not. I would also verify CakePHP's and the webserver's logs to verify which one is returning the error. If it is the webserver the webserver's config (or .htaccess files) are to be reviewed. If it is CakePHP's, then you need to keep looking at your code (and disregard this answer)